# plot the distribution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to plot the distribution of the following data. But, I don't want the histogram of it. I have attached a figure. I only one the red one. Could you please help me? thanks

[image]

Finally I want a figure like this:

[image]

```
Hsamp=normrnd(0,5,100)
g = histogram(Hsamp)
```

Comment: you can use `histfit(Hsamp(:))`, but you already know the distribution right? So why not just plot a normal distribution with your input values for `normrnd`?

Comment: No. with histfit, Matlab fit a normal distribution to the data.  I want the distribution without the fitting.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What exactly do you think the red line represents? Do you just want to plot a line instead of a bar chart? In that case, it's still a histogram, you just need to plot it differently (e.g. using the `plot` function).

Comment: Thanks @harry. I have edited the question and added another figure which I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot the histogram as a line you can retrieve the bin counts and bin edges by dot indexing the property from the histogram object, `g`:

Bin Counts → `g.BinCounts` 
Bin Edges → `g.BinEdges` 
Bin Width → `g.BinWidth`

To find the bin centres we can take all the edges start from the seconds edge and subtract half the bin width. After retrieving the bin centres and bin counts the `plot()` function can be used to plot the values against each other to produce a curve/line graph. An alternative can be to use the `histcounts()` function but the process will be pretty similar. All the properties in this histogram object can be seen in: [MATLAB Documentation: Histogram Plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html).

[image: Plotting Histogram Bars and Curves]

```
Hsamp = normrnd(0,5,100);
subplot(1,2,1); g = histogram(Hsamp);
xlabel("Bin Centres"); ylabel("Bin Counts");
Bin_Counts = g.BinCounts;
Bin_Width = g.BinWidth;
Bin_Centres = g.BinEdges(2:end) - Bin_Width;

subplot(1,2,2); plot(Bin_Centres,Bin_Counts);
xlabel("Bin Centres"); ylabel("Bin Counts");
```

---

### Extension: Binning Fundamentals

[image: Binning Fundamentals Diagram]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.